# C# program with HttpWebRequest work only through Fiddler

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, fiddler

http web request (post) not seinding directly 1 query (timeout error), if I run it through Fiddler it works perfectly.

What does Fiddler do with requests? I can't understand.

Comment: Please post your code and the whole error you are getting.

Comment: Program is not small and it tied with other parts so it will be easy to know what does Fiddler do.

Comment: My point is that it is not clear at all what *you* are doing with or without fiddler.

Comment: Just sending POST request with session. That's it.

It getting page, loggin, loading profile page and then stop on POST. No answer. With Fiddler no stops or error. So Fiddler is changing POST data or something else, I've tried to see what did the program sends with HTTP analyzer v7 and it stops like without Fiddler and I can't see sent data idk why. May be there is another good program to see POST query? I have to see what does my program send without fiddler.

Comment: I'm quite sure that Fiddler isnt changing anything.  It sends the info clearly, just as its set.  It is much more likely that you are changing the request.

Comment: Fiddler can also attach to a process and read the packets.  Perhaps you need to attack it that way.  You'd be able to see what your app is sending.

Comment: So the problem solved by EricLaw, it was my mistake because I work with C# only 1 Month after 14 years of useing Delphi :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

95% of the time, this happens because you forgot to call `.Close()` on the `GetResponseStream()`-returned object. See
http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-02-28/help!-running-fiddler-fixes-my-app-

Comment: Omg! You did it :D I forget to close GetResponseStream, only GetRequestStream was closed in requests :D Thank you, Eric!

Comment: Got a similiar issue, Use HTTPWebRequest to send patch request, and server return 403, but if fiddler is running, everything works. need help, any ideas. And not all patch request failed.. sometimes it works without fiddler.